# props is undefined but state is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working with react and I have these 3 files (component, action and reducer). Here they are:

**cart.js** looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMyWishlist } from '../actions/index';
class Cart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      this.props.fetchMyWishlist(this.props.signedInUserInfo._id);
    }
  }

  renderWishList(){
          console.log("ANOTHER TEST:"+ JSON.stringify(this.props.currentCart));
  }

  render(){
    return ({this.renderWishlist()});
  }
}



  function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("TEST: "+state.bookReducer.currentCart);
    return {
      currentCart: state.bookReducer.currentCart
    };
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchMyWishlist})(Cart);
```

My **action** is this inside action/index.js:

```
export function fetchMyWishlist(userId){
  let url = 'http://localhost:3001/cart/'+userId;
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_WISHLIST,
          payload: response.data
        });
      });
    }
}
```

Here's my **reducer**:

```
import {FETCH_BOOKS} from '../actions/types';
import {FETCH_WISHLIST} from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = { myBooks:[], currentCart:[] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BOOKS:
      return { ...state, myBooks:action.payload };
    case FETCH_WISHLIST:
      return { ...state, currentCart: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I can't understand why I get this 2 results from the 2 `console.log`s:

```
TEST: [object Object]
ANOTHER TEST: undefined
```

As you can see the reducer does its work but I can't understand why this.props.currentCart is undefined.

Comment: shouldn't the function definition of `mapStateToProps` and the `export default` statement be _after_ the closing curly brace of your `Cart` class declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrongly passing args to `JSON.stringify`. Shouldn't you use something like this

```
console.log("ANOTHER TEST: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.currentCart));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method render to:

```
renderWishList(){
          console.log(this.props.currentCart);
  }
```

it seems that your are trying to use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with a parameter that is not a json by appending "ANOTHER TEST:" and it wont work

```
//very wrong
JSON.stringify("ANOTHER TEST: "+this.props.currentCart));
```

Comment: yes you're right, I made a mistake writing the code here but the code in my computer doesnt have this typo

Comment: so if your code doesn have that problem then try to console log all your props in `renderWishList()` let see what happen

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.currentCart` will be undefined as it's context will be the window.

If you log the contents of props in the render method you should see the expected values.

See [this](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) :) article on binding context correctly